# postcss-cli command not working

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

I am trying to use postcss-cli from the commandline. I did the following steps:

```
cd ~/projects/myProject
sudo npm install --save postcss-cli
```

and then I am trying the following commands:

```
postcss --help
node_modules/.bin/postcss --help
```

But this isn't working for me. I don't even get any error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer myself. I just did a new install of nodejs and everything is working fine when I am trying the following command:

```
node_modules/.bin/postcss --help
```

This was my solution:

```
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
sudo apt-get install --yes build-essential
```

Comment: This might be helpful, although the version is now outdated, and it is unclear why this solution / workaround has been necessary at all?

Answer (score 20):

In case someone is as stupid enough as me: You also need to [install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-cli) `postcss-cli` :-)

```
npm i -D postcss postcss-cli
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Anyway, it solved my issue.

Comment: still node_modules/postcss-cli/bin/postcss: not found

Comment: Me stupid too ^^

Comment: Hello, I was stupid too. Works now!